# AssertionError: Labels must have same row count as shap values arrays

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, shap

I am trying to implement the shap.image_plot() function as it is described in the shape library documentation(link:https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/image_examples/image_classification/Multi-class%20ResNet50%20on%20ImageNet%20%28TensorFlow%29-checkpoint.html). However when running it on my own CNN model I obtain an AssertionError: Labels must have same row count as shap values arrays!

Does somebody know how to fix the error.

The data used is found under this link: https://www.kaggle.com/ahmedhamada0/brain-tumor-detection

```
import numpy as np
import shap
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import cv2
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, losses


class Data:
    def __init__(self, dataset_file_name, tumor_filename, no_tumor_filename, image_format):
        # first set of data for analysis
        self.images = []
        self.processed_images = []
        self.labels = []
        self.class_names = ["no tumor", "tumor"]

        # second set of data for feeding to model
        self.img_shape = (225, 225, 3)  # (img_width, img_height, colour channels)

        # TODO: Import dataset

        self.path_tumor = dataset_file_name+"/"+tumor_filename+"/*."+image_format
        self.path_no_tumor = dataset_file_name+"/"+no_tumor_filename+"/*."+image_format
        for filename in glob.glob(self.path_tumor):
            image = np.asarray(cv2.imread(filename))  # load dataset
            self.images.append(image)
            self.labels.append(1) # add label 1 if image has a tumor
        for filename in glob.glob(self.path_no_tumor):
            image = np.asarray(cv2.imread(filename))
            self.images.append(image)
            self.labels.append(0)

        for image in self.images:
            self.processed_images.append(preprocess_image(image))

    # convert to np array
        self.processed_images = np.asarray(self.processed_images)
        self.labels = np.asarray(self.labels)

    # convert array to float32:
        self.processed_images = self.processed_images.astype("float32")
        self.processed_images /= 255  # 1-255 (uint8) --> 0-1 (float32)


# TODO: Preprocess data -->  reshape image to (225,225,3) (width,height,colour channels)

def preprocess_image(image):
    if image.shape != (225, 225, 3):
        # fixed aspect ratio resize
        max_dimension = max(image.shape[0], image.shape[1])  # largest dimension to scale to 225
        scaling_factor = float(225 / max_dimension)  # factor by which to scale
        resized = cv2.resize(image, (0, 0), fx=scaling_factor,
                             fy=scaling_factor)  # fixed aspect ratio rescaling

        # zero padding the dimension that isn't 225px

        if resized.shape[0] != 225:  # height padding
            height_pad = 225 - resized.shape[0]  # height pad on each side of image
            width_pad = 0
        elif resized.shape[1] != 0:  # height padding
            width_pad = 225 - resized.shape[1]
            height_pad = 0
        reshaped = cv2.copyMakeBorder(resized, height_pad, 0, width_pad, 0, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 0)
        return reshaped
    else:
        return image

#load the data
data = Data("../dataset", "yes", "no", "jpg")


train_images, test_images, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(
    data.processed_images, data.labels, train_size=0.8, shuffle=True)




# TODO: Create Network

def run_model(epochs):
    # create the model
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=data.img_shape))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

    model.summary()

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=losses.binary_crossentropy,
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

    # train the model
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))

    return model
model = run_model(1)



# define a masker that is used to mask out partitions of the input image.
masker = shap.maskers.Image("inpaint_telea", test_images[0].shape)

# create an explainer with model and image masker
explainer = shap.Explainer(model.predict, masker, output_names=data.class_names)

# here we explain two images using 500 evaluations of the underlying model to estimate the SHAP values
shap_values = explainer(test_images[1:3].astype("double"), max_evals=500, batch_size=50, outputs=shap.Explanation.argsort.flip[:1])

# output with shap values
shap.image_plot(shap_values)
```

Comment: Please [reprex]. What is `data_processing` in your setup? Do you need all the saves to reproduce your error? Is your code really minimal?

Comment: The data_processing was a file I used to preprocess the images, but now I added in the functions used directly.